# Get X and Y of a shape inside a group after dragging in Konva JS

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, konvajs

I want to be able to drag and drop a group of objects (rect, text, circle, etc.) and get their new x,y position in order to keep them in that new position.

I've checked the documentation for `Konva.jS` for [dragging a group](https://konvajs.org/docs/drag_and_drop/Drag_a_Group.html), but with no luck.

What I did try is I can get the new relative `x,y` position for the group (`group.attrs.x, group.attrs.y`) but it is *not exactly the same* as the real position of any of the object inside the group. I've tried to tweak it by incrementing `x,y` but still it is different for different size of objects (in case of text with different length).

[image]

In the above image, `+22` was added to the new x and y respectively that I got from the group using `group.attrs.x, group.attrs.y`, but the resulting `circle` (dot) is different for two different objects (`rect` or `text`).

I need to get (near) *exact* `x,y` position of the circle in this case. How can I do it?

I have included here a simple demo for dragging a group of objects, at the drop it is drawing a `circle` from the `group`'s new `x,y` positions. And there you can see the difference.

```js
      
            var width = window.innerWidth;
      var height = window.innerHeight;

      var stage = new Konva.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: width,
        height: height,
      });

      var shapesLayer = new Konva.Layer();
      
      var colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'purple'];
var groups = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        var group = new Konva.Group({
        draggable: true,
      });
        var box = new Konva.Rect({
          x: i * 200 + 20,
          y: i * 180 + 20,
          width: 100,
          height: 50,
          name: colors[i],
          fill: colors[i],
          stroke: 'black',
          strokeWidth: 1,
        });
        var txt = new Konva.Text({
            x:i*200 + 20,
            y: i*180 + 20,
            text: 'Java',
            fontSize: 26
        });
        var circle = createCircle(i * 200 + 20, i * 180 + 20);
       
        group.add(box);
        group.add(txt);
        group.add(circle);
        groups.push(group);
      }

      for (let i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
          let group = groups[i];
          console.log("dragging...");
        group.on('mouseover', function () {
            document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
            
        });
        group.on('mouseout', function () {
            document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
            console.log("dropped.");
           //-------------------------QUESTION IS HERE-------------------------------
            //EN: I can get the group's new coordinates by group.attrs.x, group.attrs.y, but
             shapesLayer.add(createCircle(group.attrs.x, group.attrs.y));
             // this line is getting the new relative position of the group and creating a new circle but it is far from the real x,y of the original circle inside the group being dragNdropped.
            // how can I get the new coordinates of the group child elements?
            
//UZ: mana shu joyida group drop qilinadi, shunda rect va boshqa objectlarning x,y positionlari kerak. 
        });
        shapesLayer.add(group);
    }
    
    function createCircle(posx,posy){
      return new Konva.Circle({
              x: posx,
              y: posy,
              radius: 3,
              fill: 'red',
              stroke: 'red',
              strokeWidth: 0,
          });
        }
      stage.add(shapesLayer);
```

```css
body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #f0f0f0;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@8.3.5/konva.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Konva Drag and Drop a Group Demo</title>
   
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script>

    </script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing that stands out is you are using `mouseout` as the dropped according to the documentation there is a `dragend`, I think that is what we should be using on this case:
https://konvajs.org/docs/events/Binding_Events.html

To get the position you are looking for you need to add the group and your rectangle, take a look at the example below, it should all make sense, let me know if you have any questions.

```js
var stage = new Konva.Stage({container: 'container', width: 200, height: 200});
var shapesLayer = new Konva.Layer();

var colors = ['orange', 'green'];
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  var group = new Konva.Group({ draggable: true });
  var box = new Konva.Rect({
    x: i * 100 + 20, y: i * 80 + 20,
    width: 80, height: 50, fill: colors[i]
  });
  var circle = createCircle(i * 100 + 20, i * 80 + 20, 5, "blue");

  group.add(box);
  group.add(circle);
  group.on('dragend', dragend);
  shapesLayer.add(group);
}

function dragend(evt) {
  var rect = evt.target.children[0].attrs
  var x = evt.target.attrs.x + rect.x
  var y = evt.target.attrs.y + rect.y
  shapesLayer.add(createCircle(x, y, 2, rect.fill));
}

function createCircle(x, y, radius, fill) {
  return new Konva.Circle({ x, y, radius, fill });
}
stage.add(shapesLayer);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@8.3.5/konva.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```